how to get one query in two queries when one is empty?
I'm going to try to explain my problem in English (I'm French).. sorry for the mistakes.
I'm trying to fill a table with two queries sort by date.
I have a first sheet with some datas (DATE+NAME+DESCRIPTION+PRICE)
I have a second sheet with some other datas (DATE+NAME+DESCRIPTION+PRICE)
I would just combine all this informations in another sheet sort by date
But if a query (for example, no datas in the first sheet) is empty, I have a #value! error.
=SORT({QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z9luLttE6HX5hzXNxCeK9fAZRMDqqKvhwSG1_lnhT-o/edit?gid=0#gid=0";"Journal!$A$9:$F$200");"select Col1,Col2,Col5,Col4 where Col3='Versement Charges' and Col6='" & H1&"'";0);QUERY(Journal!$A$7:$F$213;"select Col1,Col2,Col4,Col5 where Col3='" & H1&"'";0)};1;VRAI)

I tried to change the formula with a "iferror" function... like this :
=ARRAYFORMULA(SIERREUR({SIERREUR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z9luLttE6HX5hzXNxCeK9fAZRMDqqKvhwSG1_lnhT-o/edit?gid=0#gid=0";"Journal!$A$9:$F$200");"select Col1,Col2,Col5,Col4 where Col3='Versement Charges' and Col6='" & H1&"'";0);"");SIERREUR(QUERY(Journal!$A$7:$F$213;"select Col1,Col2,Col4,Col5 where Col3='" & H1&"'";0);"")}))

but it responds me an empty cell...
I'm going to die trying to fix it and I don't understand how to skip empty datas but fill with the second sheet datas. :)
thanks !!!!

You can try using this. I used Let to create a null. I stacked the query responses using vstack, and used iferror to replace an empty query with a null value. As a note, this will still error out if both queries are null because there won't be an array to sort.
=let(z,tocol(,1),SORT(vstack(iferror(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z9luLttE6HX5hzXNxCeK9fAZRMDqqKvhwSG1_lnhT-o/edit?gid=0#gid=0","Journal!$A$9:$F$200"),"select Col1,Col2,Col5,Col4 where Col3='Versement Charges' and Col6='" & H1&"'",0),z),iferror(QUERY(Journal!$A$7:$F$213,"select Col1,Col2,Col4,Col5 where Col3='" & H1&"'",0),z)),1,1))


OH THANKS YOU !! it works ! It works so nice !!! thanks !
